# C# serial reading error

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

I'm developing a piece of software, which reads data sent through the COM port and display the value in a live graph and in a textbox (for debugging). It reads fine at first, but then suddenly one of the numbers is divided into two pieces. Like this:

63 - 64 - 65 - 66 - 67 - **6 - 8** - 69 - 70 - 80

It should say 68. This makes the graph all wrong!

What is the cause of this?

My code is as follows:

```
   private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        textBox1.AppendText(" - ");

    }



    private void comPort_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
      RxString = comPort.ReadExisting();
      this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

      newRead = Convert.ToDouble(RxString);
      AddDataToGraph(zedGraph, howfar, newRead);
      howfar++;


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no guarantee in what size chunks you will get the data....

it could get them character at a time, or several characters at a time.

Generally, never depend on timing to work out the difference between logical "chunks" ( in your case, numbers).  Instead create a protocol that you can interpret.

in your case if you have a VERY simple protocol where you send a number [space] number [space] number  then you can parse out

eg...

```
RxString += comPort.ReadExisting();  // add to an existing string
if(RxString.Contains(" ") // ok, there is a space, so we can parse out a number
{
  // parse...
  newRead = Convert.ToDouble(RxString.Substring(0,RxString.IndexOf(" "));
  RxString = RxString.Remove(0,RxString.IndexOf(" ")+1;
  AddDataToGraph(zedGraph, howfar, newRead);
  howfar++;
}
```

and if you were using 123,123,234,123,343\n

```
    RxString += comPort.ReadExisting();  // add to an existing string
    if(RxString.Contains("\n")   // ok, there is a linefeed, so we can parse out all the numbers
    {
       // parse...
       var line = RxString.Substring(0, RxString.IndexOf("\n"));
       var values = line.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
       values.ForEach(v =>  AddDataToGraph(zedGraph, howFar, Convert.ToDouble(v)));
       RxString = RxString.Remove(0, RxString.IndexOf("\n"));
       howfar++;
    }
```

Comment: +1. Beware, though, that this only parses each number when the following space is received - so if, for example, the sender sends you a string like "1 2 3 4", this code will decode "1 2 3 " and then sit waiting for a space - it will never add the "4" to the graph. This may not be an issue for you, but worth bearing in mind.

Comment: There are times when timing can be reasonably used to separate out data, especially if the time between data items is really big relative to the longest potential 'hiccup' one might encounter. For example, suppose a device sends out a chunk of data every second and the data within a chunk are guaranteed to never more than 100ms apart. Some code observes that there are no data, checks the time, observes some time later that at least 250ms later has passed, and then observes that there is still no data. In such a scenario, the code can assume data after the pause is part of a new chunk.

Comment: In many cases, it may be helpful to combine time-based decoding with other parsing. For example, suppose each variable-length data record is preceded by a certain character, but doesn't have any trailing character.  One could say an input number can be terminated either by the prefix character or by the absence of data for some confirmed length of time.  If the machine running the receive code does a level-2 garbage collection or something else that causes a hiccup, it might see several records back-to-back and not be able to see any time between them, but could still separate the records.

Comment: Is it possible to buffer the serialport until a linefeed (ASCI 10) is given? I could make a protocol that would give several values separated by a comma and then end it with a linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting smaller chunk of data than you expect. If you now how much data should be in your chunks, you should use some buffer to keep incomplete chunks and wait for remaining ones. When chunk is complete, then you should proceed with AddDataToGraph(zedGraph, howfar, newRead).